# How To Format Calendar Views in MS Project so a Custom Field Controls the Background Color?

Tags: pm-software, ms-project

In MS Project, is there a way to customize the calendar view where the value of a task level enterprise custom field drives the background color of the task?  The GanttBarFormatEx method seems to be limited to a few basic task types - milestones, critical tasks, External, marked, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there is a way to do this.  You could probably pick one custom color for the calendar bars based on the value of a custom field by writing a VBA script to check the value and set the Marked field, and then specify the color of "marked" activities.  I doubt that will be enough for your desired purpose, though.  Or, you could convince one of the project viewer companies (full disclosure -- my company Steelray is one of them) to implement this for you in their viewer.  Sounds pretty custom, though.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for adding your disclosure! Also, it's good to know that VBA is an option to customize this. I've done VBA work to customize Outlook before that the results were pretty positive. +1  :)